# Prevent continuous call of didEnterRegion() and didExitRegion() method of MonitorNotifier callback

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon

The method `didEnterRegion()` and `didExitRegion()` (MonitorNotifier Callback)calls continuously.

How can I prevent?

Answer (score 1):

This is not typical or expected behavior.  Please try running the reference application available here:

https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference

See if you get the same behavior.  If so, it may be a problem with your beacon or mobile device.  If not, it may be an issue with the way your app uses the Android Beacon Library.

Comment: You didn't declare MonitorNotifier Callback in reference application.

Comment: The reference application uses a different class to set up monitoring:  `regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);`  This RegionBootstrap automatically configures the callback to be the `this` passed in the argument.  It still works the same way under the hood.

Comment: I suggest simply running the reference app to see if you get the same entry/exit issue.  This will tell if it is a code or hardware issue.

Comment: Ok. I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply try running the reference app to see if you get the same unexpected behavior.